# How do I know that the charms bar has been opened?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

I want to dismiss my flyout when the charms bar opens up. I thought there would be an event that says that the charms has been opened, but that's not the case. What's the correct way of dismissing a flyout because the charms bar got opened?

(C#, XAML app)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is (currently) no way to detect when the charms bar is opened. You will only get notified if/when the user taps on a charm button.

That is a good behavior because users can open the charms bar just to look at the date/time, and then dismiss it to get back to your app. So, you wouldn't want to change anything just because it was opened.

When the user taps a charm button, Windows automatically closes any open Popup that has IsLightDismissEnabled == true.

Comment: Well - the behavior I am seeing is that when the charms bar opens up, apps close their flyouts. How do I then do that?

Comment: That is an out-of-the-box behavior of the Popup control. It is automatically closed by Windows.

Comment: Sorry - I am confused. I am using a Popup control and it's not automatically closed.

Comment: This behavior is enabled by: popup.IsLightDismissEnabled = true;

Comment: Ah! Did not see this property. Thanks! Will look into it further.

Comment: Bleh. Light dismiss gets rid of the popup without giving you any hooks. That means I can't animate it out.  :(

Comment: I guess I could create another popup sized at zero and use it as the "trigger" for the animation. I hate hacks. Thanks again for the answer.

Comment: "So, you wouldn't want to change anything just because it was opened." - What about real time games that automatically want to pause?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Window.Current.Activated += Current_Activated;`. It actually fires on window activation changed!

```
    void Current_Activated(object sender, WindowActivatedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.WindowActivationState == CoreWindowActivationState.CodeActivated)
        {
            if (BottomAppBarWasOpenBeforeCharmsActivated)
            {
                BottomAppBar.IsSticky = true;
                BottomAppBar.IsOpen = true;
                BottomAppBarWasOpenBeforeCharmsActivated = false;
            }

        }
        if (e.WindowActivationState == CoreWindowActivationState.Deactivated)
        {
            if (BottomAppBar.IsOpen == true)
            {
                BottomAppBarWasOpenBeforeCharmsActivated = true;
                BottomAppBar.IsSticky = false;
                BottomAppBar.IsOpen = false;
            }
        }
    }
```